# How to profile Rake task?

Tags: rake, task, profile, ruby-prof

I need to profile the rake task. Cause I'm noob I know only how to profile .rb code
like this: `ruby -Ilib -S ruby-prof -p graph_html profile.rb > profile.html`

But how do I profile a specific Rake task?

Answer (score 19):

Rake is just a Ruby script, so you should be able to just call ruby-prof against rake, in the same way you'd profile any other script.

Given your invocation of ruby-prof, try:

```
ruby -Ilib -S ruby-prof -p graph_html `which rake` TASK > profile.html
```

I've just used the following command line:

```
ruby-prof -p graph_html /usr/local/bin/rake19 import_from_aws file=~/sourcedata batch=test1 > /tmp/profile.html
```

To profile an invocation of:

```
rake19 import_from_aws file=~/sourcedata batch=test1
```

Comment: The `\`which rake\`` does the trick… I didn't knew `ruby-prof` required the complete path of the ruby script to profile.

Comment: For those using **rbenv** use `rbenv which rake`

Comment: @collimarco Should they be surrounded by backticks, like `\`rbenv which rake\``?

Answer (score 1):

If you want 'coarse' profiling and want to find out which task is the bottleneck, I suggest Mike William's excellent piece of code from [here](http://dogbiscuit.org/mdub/weblog/Tech/Programming/Ruby/RakeProfiling). It worked beautifully when I was profiling my Rake tasks.

```
module Rake
  class Task
    def execute_with_timestamps(*args)
      start = Time.now
      execute_without_timestamps(*args)
      execution_time_in_seconds = Time.now - start
      printf("** %s took %.1f seconds\n", name, execution_time_in_seconds)
    end

    alias :execute_without_timestamps :execute
    alias :execute :execute_with_timestamps 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's worth mentioning that you might want to profile it using bundle instead of rake directly if you happen to be using bundler.

`` ruby-prof -p graph_html `which bundle` -- 'exec' 'rake' '-T' > profile.html ``